# Return fiscal quarter from dataframe date column with custom string in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
    quarter = pd.Timestamp(dt.date(2020, 1, 1)).quarter
    assert quarter == 1

    df['quarter'] = df['date'].dt.quarter
```

This returns a 1,2,3 or 4 in df['quarter'] depending on the date in column df['date'].

What I would like to have is this format in column df['quarter']:

Qx-2019 or Qx-2020 depending on the year, where x is the quarter found with the script above.

How can I get the specific year from the quarter and add the formt Qx-year?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `to_period`

```
s.dt.to_period('Q')
Out[159]: 
0    2020Q4
1    2019Q1
dtype: period[Q-DEC]
```

Update

```
'Q' + df['date'].dt.quarter.astype(str) + '-' + df['date'].dt.year.astype(str)
```

Comment: great thanks! what if I need another format, like Q4-2020?